# Game platforms emulators on Xbmc/Openelec

Tags: emulation, openelec, kodi

Is it possible to run emulators on Xbmc/Openelec?
I am familiar with an addon "Rom Collection Browser" and as my understanding of this plugin is that it can launch various games with different emulators. However I haven't managed to do anything useful with it.

I have deduced that I need an emulator either on my raspberry PI or somewhere else remotely.

So my question is:

- what are some most recommended emulators on raspberry PI (I haven't found any)?
- or how could one run an remote emulator to play games on raspberry PI?

In both cases I'm thinking about some very basic emulators (SNES/MAME etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XBMC supports starting external applications like MAME arcade emulator from it. MAME on Pi:
http://blog.sheasilverman.com/2012/11/better-advancemame-debs-with-sound/
http://ipggi.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/mame-arcade-game-fun-with-a-raspberry-pi/
http://www.newsdownload.co.uk/pages/RPiMameGpioJoystick.html

Answer (score 1):

I use RetroPie to have all-in-one emulator on raspberry PI. Work perfectly with 2 controler and with this kind of emulation:

- GameBoy / GameBoy Color
- GameBoy Advance (need some tweak)
- NES/SNES
- Master system
- x86 (dos games)

You can take the RetroPie folder to put on xbmc after the installation.